# Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -11). Memory limit too low or maximum file number of subprocess reached. Message : b'' Odoo 14 CE

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, wkhtmltopdf, odoo-14

> The error is coming only while printing reports which has more than
> 150 pages.

```
wkhtmltopdf version : 0.12.5 (with patched qt) 
OS         : Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS 
CPU(s)     : 48 
Memory(RAM): 94GB
```

ulimit -a

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 377646
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 200000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 200000
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

odoo configuration file

```
limit_memory_hard = 78114717696
limit_memory_soft = 65095598080
```

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear: you're running out of resources.  Split the report into several smaller prints, or look at [these articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=wkhtmltopdf+memory+limit+too+low).

Comment: @RobertHarvey i have updated my question with specifying the memory space i have,
I have already tried these solutions you have mentioned.
None of them have faced issue with wkhtmltopdf version 0.12.5 (with patched qt).

Comment: Can you roll back to a version that does not have this problem?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Previous versions like 0.12.4 wont cause this memory issue, but it will not keep the report fomat correctly.It prints the data as overlaped.